# Add space between columns in gt()

Tags: r, gt

[image]I am dealing with a considerable volume of data and aim to enhance the visual clarity of the tables I have generated.

Referring to the following example, I want to expand the separation between the three main sections of the figure. To be more precise, I am looking to introduce greater spacing between Part 1 and Part 2, as well as between Part 2 and Part 3.

I appreciate any help. Thank you very much

```
library(gt)

exibble |>
  gt(rowname_col = "row", groupname_col = "group") |>
  summary_rows(
    groups = "grp_a",
    columns = c(num, currency),
    fns = c("min", "max")
  ) |>
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = currency,
    fns = total ~ sum(., na.rm = TRUE)
  ) |>
  tab_source_note(source_note = "This is a source note.") |>
  tab_footnote(
    footnote = "This is a footnote.",
    locations = cells_body(columns = 1, rows = 1)
  ) |>
  tab_header(
    title = "The title of the table",
    subtitle = "The table's subtitle"
  ) |>
  tab_spanner(label = md("**Part 1**"),
              columns = c(num, char),
              level = 2
  )|>
  tab_spanner(label = md("**Part 2**"),
              columns = c(fctr, date, time),
              level = 2
  )|>
  tab_spanner(label = md("**Part 3**"),
              columns = c(datetime, currency),
              level = 2)][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert extra columns between the groups using `cols_add`, and then rename the columns to white space using `cols_label` to make them (mostly) vanish.  You can also add the argument `missing_text = ""` to `summary_rows` and `grand_summary_rows`.

```
  cols_add('TEST1' = '', .after = 'char') |>
  cols_add('TEST2' = '', .after = 'time') |>
  cols_label('TEST1' = md('&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;'),
             'TEST2' = md('&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before by adding a conditional style to one of the columns, giving only that column a wider border, thus giving the impression of space between columns. You need to set the `columns` argument in the `cells_body()` function with the name of the column you want to space:

```
table |> 
      tab_style(
        style = cell_borders(sides = "left", color = "white", weight = px(12), style = "solid"),
        locations = cells_body(
          columns = column_that_needs_space)
      )
```